# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, chatbot

when running this script, I get an error when calling the model.fit(dataset, epochs=5) method when I want to train the model and I get the error InvalidArgumentError: Graph executes error:

`

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')

def preprocess_data(data):
  # Tokenize as sentences
  data = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in data]

  # Remove stopwords
  stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('portuguese')
  data = [[word for word in sent if word not in stopwords] for sent in data]

  # Perform lemmatization
  lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
  data = [[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sent] for sent in data]

  return data

# Example usage
data = [  "oi tudo bem?", "sim, eu estou com fome e voce?", "eu estou, quero uma pizza", "vou pedir duas pizzas", "Gosto de livros", "quais livros voce gosta de ler?", "oi tudo bem?",     "sim, eu estou com fome e voce?",     "eu estou, quero uma pizza",     "vou pedir duas pizzas",     "Gosto de livros",     "quais livros voce gosta de ler?",    "eu gosto de ler thrillers e ficção científica",     "e você, o que mais gosta de ler?",    "eu também gosto de ler romances e livros de autoajuda",     "qual é o seu livro favorito?",    "um dos meus livros favoritos é o 'O Alquimista' de Paulo Coelho",     "eu também gosto muito desse livro! Qual é o seu gênero literário favorito?",    "eu gosto de todos os gêneros, mas talvez meu favorito seja a ficção científica",     "eu também adoro ficção científica. Qual é o seu livro de ficção científica favorito?",    "meu livro de ficção científica favorito é 'Dune' de Frank Herbert",     "que legal, eu também gosto muito de 'Dune'! Já leu algum outro livro do Frank Herbert?",    "sim, eu também gostei muito de 'O Imperador-Deus de Dune' e 'Herejia de Dune'"]
processed_data = preprocess_data(data)
print(processed_data)


import tensorflow as tf

# Define the input and output sequences
input_sequences = processed_data[:-1]
output_sequences = processed_data[1:]

def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

# Create a vocabulary of unique words
vocab = sorted(set(flatten(input_sequences + output_sequences)))

# Create word-to-index and index-to-word mappings
word_to_index = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(vocab)}
index_to_word = {i: word for i, word in enumerate(vocab)}

# Convert the input and output sequences to integers
input_sequences = [[word_to_index[word] for word in seq] for seq in input_sequences]
output_sequences = [[word_to_index[word] for word in seq] for seq in output_sequences]

# Find the maximum sequence length
max_seq_len = max(len(seq) for seq in input_sequences + output_sequences)

# Pad the sequences with zeros to the maximum sequence length
input_sequences = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    input_sequences, maxlen=max_seq_len, padding='post')
output_sequences = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    output_sequences, maxlen=max_seq_len, padding='post')

# Create a dataset from the padded sequences
batch_size = 32  # Replace 32 with the desired batch size
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (input_sequences, output_sequences)).batch(batch_size)

# Define the RNN model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(vocab), 64, input_length=max_seq_len),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(vocab), activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Treinar o modelo
model.fit(dataset, epochs=5)
```

`

I hope to be able to train the network, but the error returned is InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Answer (score 0):

I have also received the same error message that you have. I am looking to program an image classification system with TensorFlow that completes the training on a Google Compute Engine Virtual Machine. I included the stack trace for my issue for more information as well. I haven't found very strong information to fix this model training step on the internet so far.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/MOUNTED_HD1/gschindl/code/GeoShapeFull.py", line 215, in <module>
    history = drop_model.fit(
  File "/home/gschindl/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/gschindl/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 52, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Input is empty.
         [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5251]
```

Comment: If you find anything, please share it.